# error comando python discord

Tags: python, discord.py

hola muy buenas tengo un pequeño error

Tengo un bot en discord y cuando ingreso un comando que no tiene nada que ver con el bot me sale el error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "hola" is not found
```

tengo este código que podría solucionar este error pero no sé por qué no funciona: este es el código:

```
@commandname.error
async def commandname_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.errorname):
        await ctx.send(add a custom message, or you can do f"{error}".)
```

Tambien tengo este codigo:

```
    @bot.event 
async def on_command_error(ctx, error): 
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound): 
        em = discord.Embed(title=f".", description=f".", color=ctx.author.color) 
        await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

Este ultimo si funciona pero el problema es si tengo dos bots activados pasa lo siguiente:
[image: bot discord]

Actualmente estoy usando varios bots y no se como podria solucionar para que no se ejecute este comando.

Comment: Tienes abiertos varios bots o varios programas que se conectan al mismo token? Por que el gif muestra que el bot envia el mismo mensaje dos veces, cosa que no haces en tu código.

Comment: Tengo dos bots abiertos con el mismo token, y ejecuto los dos en otro bot:     

import subprocess


subprocess.Popen('python bot1.py')


Para no tener que abrir varias consolas

Comment: No se la solución y no creo que exista una. Si abres dos scripts y ambos se conectan al mismo bot, ambos van a responder. Por que quieres abrir dos scripts en primer lugar? No alcanza con un programa abierto?

Comment: Pensandolo bien, veo una posible solución... quizá... peeeero antes quiero que me cuentes el por que de usar dos scripts para el mismo bot.

Comment: Usan diferentes codigos y estoy usando el mismo token

Comment: Y por que usas diferentes códigos? Cuando el bot debe funcionar según el primer código y cuando debe funcionar con el otro? Hay algún evento especifico? Es por motivos de prueba?

Comment: Ya esta solucionado!